# MSAccess VBA Shell: UNZIP

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using a simple ZIP/UNZIP utility (http://infozip.sourceforge.net/) called from a WScript.Shell.

```
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Databases\"
strPathUtil = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Databases\DB_Utilities\"

ChDir strPath
strCMD = strPathUtil & "UNZIP.exe -o Item_4892.zip"
fShellRun (strCMD)
```

I get NO result & no complaint with this approach.  The resulting strCMD looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Backend_Databases\DB_Utilities\UNZIP.exe -o Item_4892.zip
```

This line works from a Command Window exactly as expected.  fShellRun works as expected for other Shell Commands in use in my AccessDB.

Note:  I could swear this was working like last week during initial testing, but I just cannot seem to figure this out now; it is making me completely batty!  Maybe I am just too close to this and I am missing something obvious.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you extracting Windows Compression zip folders? Don't really need a 3rd party tool for that.

Comment: A bunch of my users (contractor in India) do not have the built-in Windows ZIP function available - for whatever reason.

Comment: The Windows Compression tool is probably there somewhere. Happened to me once, lost it and had to somehow restore it. Just don't remember what I had to do. On another occasion I had WinZip (long time ago when it was free) and that somehow overrode WindowsCompression. I removed WinZip and WC became available. Sorry, since I am not interested in downloading tool, can't test and no idea why your code fails.

Comment: June7, frustrations of 3rd party vendor.  Been thru this discussion with them, thus the use of the external utility.  My AccessDB detects if installed and grabs from FTP if missing from any user machines at time of use - no install, no registry concerns.  Been a good approach for nearly 8 years,  Just not sure what is up this week.

Comment: I am suspecting my issue is with the PATHS used to locate the UNZIP utility, the ZIP file and then wherever the resulting csv will land.   I can use ANY BOGUS value for these paths and I do not see a complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works.  My original fShellRun was customized for other purposes long ago and not compatible with this task.

The following is very simple and functional, runs silently:

```
Private Sub UnzipTest_Click()

Dim oShell
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim strPathUtil As String

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")

strFile = Me!txtFilename
strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Databases\"
strPathUtil = CurrentProject.Path & "\Backend_Databases\DB_Utilities\"

strCMD = strPathUtil & "UNZIP.exe -o " & strPath & strFile & " -d " & strPath

oShell.Run strCMD, 0, True

Set oShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note:  This points to a 3rd party UNZIP utility, vs the std Windows ZIP utility.  The UNZIP.exe is kept in my "...\DB_Utilities" folder. 
 http://infozip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For a solution without 3rd party utilities, check of my [Compression and decompression methods for VBA](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress)

Comment: Gustav, very interesting.  I will wade thru to see what might be workable for me.  Are there an identifiable subset of functions I can reduce to narrowly support ZIP and UNZIP only?   I've let my ExpertsExchange sub lapse.

Comment: Indeed: _Zip_ and (surprise) _UnZip_.

Comment: Gustav, I have a couple questions. Can we take them offline via StackOverflow?

Comment: Sure. You could post them on [GitHub](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress/issues) or leave comments to the linked article at [Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31130/Zip-and-unzip-files-and-folders-with-VBA-the-Windows-Explorer-way.html).